# md-tab causes $digest already in progress error

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

When switching the tabs in md-tab directive I get error message below. Note that I neither see the error when running the code in Codepen nor when opening the index.html directly in the browser. But when I choose to host index.html (placed in app folder) through ExpressJS and Node I see this error. See the two files below.

**Dependencies:**

- Angular v1.4.0-rc.2
- Angular Material (master branch)
- Express v4.12.3
- Node v0.12.3

**Error message displayed in console:**

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:68)
at beginPhase (angular.js:16056)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15800)
at Scope.scopePrototype.$apply (hint.js:1478)
at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (hint.js:797)
at HTMLElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3247)
at redirectFocus (angular-material.js:12919)
at Object.handleFocusIndexChange [as fn] (angular-material.js:12915)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15539)
at Scope.scopePrototype.$digest (hint.js:1468)
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular Material Tabs</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">
    </head>
    
    <body ng-app="mdTabsApp" layout="column">
    <md-content class="md-padding" flex layout="row" layout-align="center start" style="background-color: #eee;">
        <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs="always"
                 md-border-bottom
                 class="md-whiteframe-z2"
                 flex
                 style="background-color:#ffffff">
            <md-tab>
                <md-tab-label>Tab 1</md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body class="md-padding">
                    Tab 1 content
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab>
                <md-tab-label>Tab 2</md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body class="md-padding">
                    Tab 2 content
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab>
                <md-tab-label>Tab 3</md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body class="md-padding" >
                    Tab 3 content
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.2/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.2/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        (function (angular, undefined) {
            "use strict";
            angular.module('mdTabsApp', [
                'ngMaterial'
            ])
        })(angular);
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**app.js**

```js
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('app'));

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: So I created a [runnable](http://runnable.com/VVTltKLzNt5xHAEt/md-tab-causes-%24digest-already-in-progress-error-for-express-and-node-js) and got no errors.

Comment: i'm also getting this but only with angular-material#0.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an local mistical bug in my Chrome, as I can´t reproduce the error in Codepen/Runnable nor in Firefox. See also discussion in https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2850

You can find the complete sample here: https://github.com/ismarslomic/material-tabs-uirouter